# rails array with multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create an array that has multiple internal fields so that at the time of rendering I can save the fields of each one, something like this:

```
@profile = [{module:"user", Description:"module of users"},{module:"products", Description:"module of products"}]
```

to render and create records this way:

```
@profile.each do |prof|
    Record.create(module: prof.module, Description: prof.descripcion)
end
```

but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `module' for {:module=>"users", :description=>"module of users"}:Hash):
  app/controllers/usuarios_controller.rb:31:in `block in busqueda_usuario_perfil'
  app/controllers/usuarios_controller.rb:30:in `each'
  app/controllers/usuarios_controller.rb:30:in `busqueda_usuario_perfil'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hash and keys are symbols, so you need to use `h[:s]`:

```
@profile.each do |prof|
  Record.create(module: prof[:module], description: prof[:descripcion])
end
```

But as the keys are equal you could do better:

```
@profile.each do |prof|
  Record.create(prof)
end
```

And I would use lowercase for the keys.

Answer (score 1):

To access to hash use square brackets instead of dot.

Try use this:

```
@profile.each do |prof|
  Record.create(module: prof['module'], Description: prof['Description'])
end
```

Comment: no longer shows me the error but when saving the records the fields are null